# Airflow 1.10.10 [core] vs 1.10.15[logging] AWS S3 Remote Logging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow

I am not able to enable remote logging to `AWS S3` after moving loggin setup from `[core]` to `[logging]` section?

This is what I moved:

```
[logging]
# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /usr/local/airflow/logs

# Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage or Elastic Search.
# Users must supply an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
# location. If remote_logging is set to true, see UPDATING.md for additional
# configuration requirements.
remote_logging = True
remote_log_conn_id = MyS3Conn
remote_base_log_folder = s3://bucket/tst/
encrypt_s3_logs = False

# Logging level
logging_level = INFO
fab_logging_level = WARN

# Logging class
# Specify the class that will specify the logging configuration
# This class has to be on the python classpath
# logging_config_class = my.path.default_local_settings.LOGGING_CONFIG
logging_config_class =

# Log format
# we need to escape the curly braces by adding an additional curly brace
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s

# Log filename format
# we need to escape the curly braces by adding an additional curly brace
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
# Name of handler to read task instance logs.
# Default to use task handler.
task_log_reader = task
```

I just move the properties.
`airflow upgrade_check`  returns that `Logging configuration has been moved to new section` check is okei.

I have `apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3,log]==1.10.15`, when all the properties that are now under `logging` were in `core` remote logging was working fine.

I do not find any information regarding how to setup it. I only found [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md) but it only says that the following configurations have been moved from [core] to the new [logging] section.

Answer (score 3):

You should continue use `[core]` for logging in 1.10.15, only when you update to Airflow >= 2.0.0, you should use `[logging]` section.

The `upgrade_check` command says it has been moved to `[logging]` section in >=2.0.0. It will keep working just raise a deprecation warning.

Comment: Oh nice, thanks for the feedback. I thought it was related already in the 1.10.15